# process running in background but still I cannot use the command line

Tags: background-process

[image]I suspend a running process by ctrl+Z and the bg to place process in the background but the process still running in the foreground so I cannot use the command line. How can I put the process completely in the background so I can use the command line?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, [please edit your post to include additional context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/500952/edit). What terminal emulator are you using? What operating system are you using? Thank you!

Comment: An example showing this behaviour would be nice to see.

Comment: even if it's put in background, a process can still write stuff to your terminal. there are various hacky way to force redirect its output somewhere else (maybe someone can prove wrong and show some nice standard way of doing that) -- but the moral is that you should start your background program as `prog >logfile 2>&1 &` or `prog >/dev/null 2>&1 &` if you don't want to see its output.

Comment: Please edit your question to answer the questions in the comments. This question is marked as a duplicate, and will close soo. If you re-edit your question it will be reviewed again.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong idea about what foreground and background mean when it comes to terminal job control.  They are not determined by whether you can see output.

A terminal device (more specifically, the line discipline) has a *foreground process group ID* associated with it.  This determines what process group the line discipline sends signals to, when it is in canonical mode and receives one of the special characters that maps to a signal (which is information that is also held in the line discipline).

Job-control shells allocate process groups to the processes that comprise shell jobs, and switch the terminal device's foreground process group among these process groups, and its own process group, in order to perform job control.

This does not by default affect output, to the terminal from those processes.  There is *only one* circumstance where this affects output, which is when you have turned the `tostop` flag on in the line discipline (with `stty` or some such command).  This flag being on is *not the default*.  (There are just two exceptions that I know of: one can set default initial settings on some operating systems, but only for *real* terminals, e.g. [sio devices](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sio&sektion=4) on FreeBSD; and my [`vc-reset-tty`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/vc-reset-tty.xml) tool sets this flag on when resetting to "sane" state.)

As such, if you have shell jobs running that generate output, that output *will* be intermingled with the shell's output.

The alternative of turning `tostop` on will not help you here.  You have a shell job that generates output *continually*.  It is apparently outputting *an interactive progress display*.  Terminal job control does not marry well to *continually interactive programs*.  (Text editors like `vi` and text file viewers like `more`, in contrast, are not *continually* interactive.)  Your choices are `tostop` off and the progress display mixing with that of other processes, or `tostop` on and the progress display causing the program to be halted at each progress update.

Or, on the gripping hand, using two terminals.

## Further reading

- [Difference between process group and job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9082/5132)
- [What is the difference between a job and a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4214/5132)
- [Shell's process group ID = foreground job's process group ID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232164/5132)
- [Who changes the foreground process group of a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403530/5132)
- [Are all of the signals sent from the terminal gets sent to the foreground process group?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403587/5132)
- [Which process group does my program belong to when started from bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222449/5132)
- [Can Ctrl+C send the SIGINT signal to multiple processes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/365463/5132)
- [Will a child process be in a different process group than the parent process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403064/5132)
- [Why is SIGINT not propagated to child process when sent to its parent process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149741/5132)
- [What is the purpose of abstractions, session, session leader and process groups?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82844/5132)
- [What is the purpose of the controlling terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404555/5132)
- [Background, zombie, daemon and without ctty - are these concepts connected?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352781/5132)
- … and *many* more.